# How to get MySQL successive timestamp differences?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to compute the timestamp differences for successive rows in a MYSQL table, but also within groups in that table.

The data look like this:

```
"PK"    "GROUP" "STEP"  "STATUS"    "TIMESTAMP" "CORRECT_DIFF"
"1" "1" "1" "N" "13/5/2021 09:00:00"                "900"
"2" "1" "2" "A" "13/5/2021 09:15:00"                "1800"
"3" "1" "3" "T" "13/5/2021 09:45:00"    
"4" "2" "1" "N" "13/5/2021 10:15:00"                "2700"
"5" "2" "2" "A" "13/5/2021 11:00:00"                "1200"
"6" "2" "3" "T" "13/5/2021 11:20:00"
```

There are groups 1 and 2. Within those groups there can be as many steps as needed, but 3 steps are shown above for each group.

I have a basic query working but it doesn't respect the grouping and I'm having trouble figuring out how to get that.

Here is my query thus far:

```
SELECT
 A.`TIMESTAMP`,
    A.`GROUP`,
    A.PK,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF( SECOND, A.TIMESTAMP, B.TIMESTAMP ) AS TS_DIFF,
    A.CORRECT_DIFF AS TS_DIFF_Correct
FROM
    workflow A
    INNER JOIN workflow B ON B.PK = A.PK + 1 
ORDER BY
    PK ASC
```

Which gives the correct values, but also calculates the difference from one group to the next.

How do I modify the query above so that it only computes the successive row differences within a group (1 or 2 above)?

Perhaps a MySQL 8 window function?

Thanks very much in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User `LEAD()`:

```
SELECT wf.*
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, wf.TIMESTAMP,
                     LEAD(wf.TIMESTAMP) OVER (PARTITION BY `Group` ORDER BY  wf.TIMESTAMP)
                    ) AS TS_DIFF
FROM workflow wf
ORDER BY PK ASC
```

Comment: Brilliant! And so compact. Thank you!